# Retag a4j to ajax4jsf

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are 2 tags for [Ajax4jsf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax4jsf).

- [ajax4jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax4jsf) (currently 20 questions)
- [a4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a4j) (currently 68 questions)

Since a4j is actually the library prefix like as in `<html xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">`, I wanted to propose it as a synonym for the full name ajax4jsf. However, since this has less questions, I was not able to suggest it as synonym.

So, could someone please retag a4j to ajax4jsf so that I can propose the synonym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody seems to care, I've finally given up and proposed the [ajax4jsf](/questions/tagged/ajax4jsf) as [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/a4j/synonyms) of [a4j](/questions/tagged/a4j).

I can live with that.